# Can I cache a result using the Twitter gem? (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, twitter, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the [Twitter Gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter).

My Model:

```
class TweetyClass
  def initialize
    @client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key        = TWITTER_CONFIG['consumer_key']
      config.consumer_secret     = TWITTER_CONFIG['consumer_secret']
      config.access_token        = TWITTER_CONFIG['access_token']
      config.access_token_secret = TWITTER_CONFIG['access_token_secret']
    end
  end

  def user_timeline
    @client.user_timeline( count: 2)
  end
end
```

My Controller:

```
def tweets
  @tweets = TweetyClass.new.user_timeline
end
```

My View:

```
<% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>

  <li><%= tweet.foo%></li>

<% end %>
```

Is there a way to cache the results so each time I call **user_timeline** it fetches the result from the app/app variable rather than going to Twitter and fetching the timeline of Tweets.

Apologies if I'm not using the correct terminology; I'm new to the subject of caching. Essentially what I want to do is improve the speed of my app and one thing that seems to slow it down is the time it takes to retrieve tweets using the user_timeline method. I'm assuming it's because it's retrieving this from Twitter each time and I thought caching may assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it with memcached but you have to setup your environment first.

1) Install memcached

```
sudo apt-get install memcached (ubuntu)
brew install memcached (mac os x)
```

2) Add dalli to => Gemfile

```
gem 'dalli'
```

3) Change environments/development.rb

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

4) Finally your_controller.rb

```
@tweets = Rails.cache.fetch("your_unique_cache_key_name") do
  TweetyClass.new.user_timeline
end
```

You can learn more from [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-memcached-with-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts) tutorial.